# LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE large file?

Tags: php, mysql, csv, load-data-infile

I'm importing **.CSV** files into mySQL using **LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE**, and it's working for all my test files (which are relativity small).

The problem occurs when I try using the real file I want to work with, which is **97MB** in size. Is there a limit to the file size I can upload? If there is, how can I overcome it? My code for the query is below:

```
// Import csv data in table in respective rows.

    $sql = "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '$csvFileForLoad' INTO TABLE $tableName 
            FIELDS TERMINATED BY '~'
            LINES TERMINATED BY '\\r\\n'
            IGNORE 1 LINES
            (@ignore, name, age, gender)";


// Execute query

    if (mysqli_query($con,$sql)) {
      echo "Table populated successfully.\n";
    } else {
      echo "Error populating table: " . mysqli_error($con) . ".\n";
    }
```

Thanks!

Comment: There is a filesize limit in php. Look [here](https://www.drupal.org/node/97193)

Comment: and maximum execution time [http://php.net/manual/tr/function.set-time-limit.php]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look inside your php.ini - There should be a setting to tweak in there

```
upload_max_filesize = 10M
post_max_size = 10M
```

Also check your vhosts and htaccess files as they may have something like

```
php_value upload_max_filesize 10M
php_value post_max_size 10M
```

Don't forget to restart your webserver ;-)

HTHs! Thanks, //P

Comment: I can't seem to find php.ini in my phpMyAdmin files. Any idea where it may be hiding?

Comment: It is generally included under your /etc/ directory on most *nix based systems but check your php.ini - afraid this will take a bit of commandline work ;-) or talking to your provider

Comment: Awesome, found it! Now... How do I restart the server without loosing any of the data? (I'm new to this s sorry for all the questions!)

Comment: Np Buddy - to restarting the webserver depends on what distro and Webserver you are using try - sudo service apache restart

That should sort the webserver bit out ;-)